# PHP - merge two arrays using index but remove extras from second array

Tags: php, arrays

First array

```
array (size=3) 
  25 => int 0 
  26 => int 0 
  24 => int 0
```

Second array

```
array (size=7) 
  25 => int 5 
  26 => int 0 
  24 => int 7 
  21 => int 0 
  22 => int 0 
  23 => int 0 
  28 => int 0
```

Expected array

```
array (size=3) 
  25 => int 5 
  26 => int 0 
  24 => int 7
```

I have tried functions like `array_merge()`, but no luck. So can someone help me to merge?

Comment: *I have tried* Please show us your attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)**.

```
$result = array_intersect_key($array2, $array1);
```

Note: the order of the parameters is important.